missing error prompt in Windows PowerShell
If I run a program in cmd and the program needs a dll that is missing, an error dialog pops up showing this error. However, in PowerShell, no such dialog pops up, and the program silently quits without any hint. This is not good because I don't know if the program has run successfully(just no output) or did not run at all.
Is there an option in PowerShell that I can turn on to show this kind of error dialog?

Something along these lines? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359427/try-catch-on-executable-exe-in-powershell

I don't get what error dialog you could be referring to. Please provide a screenshot and maybe instructions to provoke the error.

Not wanting to write code isn't much of an excuse when you wrote the application yourself. Also, cmd and ps are two different things, so an application running in one should be expected not to behave the same running in the other. More details about your application, as well as an awareness that these are two different systems, even if they have significant overlap or cross-compatibility, is key to getting you to a good solution

@music2myear I think a better solution is to let MS fix the bug. To achieve that goal, we must let more people aware of that bug.

try {test.exe} catch {$Error[0]}

about_Try_Catch_Finally
about_Automatic_Variables

Thanks, but I do not want to write code. I run the program directly in a PowerShell window as in cmd window which shows the error dialog without any additional code.

@William So, what command do you run?

,Key7 The program is written by myself which depends on a dll. I forgot to deploy that dll so the error occurred.

What is funny is that PowerShell does not seem that powerful. It seems less powerful than the old cmd. Apart from the talked issue, here is another example: in cmd I can run a program in current directory by just typing its name yourapp, but in PowerShell it cannot find the program and you have to type ./yourapp.exe.

@William I've seen a simple PowerShell loop replace many lines of complex CMD/batch logic so it depends on the need, your exposure, understanding, and actually trying things sometimes. If launching some executable with PowerShell does not give desired output by default, then stick with CMD if that's what it was developed to work with. Otherwise, you might want to take your developed app back to the drawing board once you understand how it will interactive with PowerShell and work that out before you expect it to work the same way it does with CMD when just calling it.

@William You can always post your source code from your exe project and post a question on StackOverflow how to fix the logic at that level to work with the way you desire it to work when launched from PowerShell. It is true powershell and cmd are not the same thing, so you should not expect them to work the same way.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle The problem is not related to specific app. It is a common problem. Normally, if a program cannot start due to missing dlls, the system should report this error. I think it is not necessary to post my source code somewhere to get this issue solved. Yes, I can switch to cmd, but Microsoft does want me to switch to PowerShell. I can run cmd in the past by pressing the shift key and right-clicking on the explorer, but now cmd is replaced by PowerShell on the context menu.

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16468, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012332/how-to-make-powershell-tell-me-about-missing-dlls, seems like a known bug.


Is there an option in PowerShell that I can turn on to show this kind of error dialog?

No, there is no option in PowerShell that you can turn on to show error dialogs.
Errors can only be captured programmatically (see Mr.Key7's answer) or via examining output generated by a script.
